# Javascript used in PHP, does this run on the server or in the client?

Tags: javascript, php

For example:

```
echo "<script type\"javascript\"> alert('HELLO ALL')</script>";
```

PHP runs on the server and Javascript runs in client.

When we echo Javascript in PHP, where will this javascript code run? On the server side or client side?

Comment: What does [the documentation](http://php.net/echo) say echo does? What does the source code of the HTML look like after you get it from the PHP program on the server?

Comment: you want short answer or long answer ? the short answer in client .

Answer (score 1):

PHP renders the HTML/CSS/JS source code which then gets sent to and executed on the client side. The echo line runs on the server. The output JavaScript code is run on the client.

Answer (score 0):

PHP takes whatever is in as a PHP's function, PHP's variable, PHP's comment or plain text (could it be HTML/JS/CSS/...)

```
Server --> PHP, ... (cares only PHP)
Client --> Javascript, HTML, CSS, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

echo function basically outputs whatever you enclose between the quotes to the requesting client(in this case a browser).Browser then renders or processes the output received from the php script as per its mime type. In your case you are echoing a JavaScript code wrapped in a script tag. When the browser encounter the script tag in the received data, it interprets the following js code locally(on clients computer.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP script if placed between PHP tags as follows:

```
<?php echo "<script type\"javascript\"> alert('HELLO ALL')</script>"; ?>
```

will generate the specified JavaScript which runs on the front-end.  The PHP script should properly be placed in an HTML page either in the body or the HEAD section.

If you wished you could abandon the script tags and using jQuery you could use the PHP code to generate the value of an event-property attribute.  The code below targets the click event when a user clicks anywhere in the document's body and causes the JavaScript that has already been provided by PHP to execute, as follows:

```
<script>
$(document).click( 
    function() {
    <?php    
        echo "alert(\"Hi to the purple fish in the deep blue sea\")\n";
    ?>    
    console.log('Document is clicked!');
    });
</script>
```

If you do a view source no one can tell looking at the code that PHP generated it!  Think of it this way: The server code executes first and then the front-end, which includes JavaScript/jQuery, executes next.

Answer (score 0):

Once the webpage is loaded, all

```
echo
```

on your php file will be executed from the server side.

thus, whatever your echo's contain will be written on the page source (client side).

considering, that script will still be on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of echo is to print out. In your case, the javascript will be printed out on browser and will be executed by browser (client).